# Activity это отдельная программа?

Tags: android, activity, ipc

читаю книгу "Эффективное использование потоков в ос Anroid" и там есть глава о взаимодействии между процессами. Там говориться что Intent использует IPC. Значит ли это что каждая активность с точки зрения джавы является отдельной программой запускаемой с помощью Intent?

Comment: На днях читал статью о том что нужно всем переходить на единую активность для всего приложения, так как при переходе для каждой активности запускается процесс run, stop, create и т.д. не знаю является ли это отдельной программой, но переход все же болезненный

Answer (score 1):

**Не уверен.** Т.к. все `activity` в приложениях подписанные одним сертификатом по умолчанию запускаются в одном процессе. И у андроид приложений нет единой точки входа `main()`. Им может стать любой компонент. То на ваш вопрос можно ответить - нет, в пределах одного приложения.

Comment: Единая точка как раз есть, но назначить этой точкой можно любой активити

Comment: @ArtyMorris эмм, это и написано в ответе. Точкой входа может быть не только активити, но и любой компонент

Comment: Я имел ввиду что это всё равно прописывается в манифесте. Точка входа

Comment: @dinario а что еще кроме активити может быть точкой входа?

Comment: @dinario вы не подскажете, где можно прочесть о сертификате которым подписываются активности

Comment: Единая точка есть - это экземпляр класса Application метод onCreate()

Comment: @Dranik любой компонент(сервис, широковещательный приемник и тд), почитайте про компоненты. Подписывается не активность, а приложение. В интернете полно инфы

Comment: @Style-7 Согласно документации, у андроида нет единой точки входа([Android apps don't have a single entry point](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals)). А также, что `onCreate` класса Application запускается не всегда([excluding content providers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application))

Comment: @Style-7 Если не прав, поправьте

Comment: @dinario в каких случаях onCreate может пропускаться?

Comment: @Dranik при доступе к провайдеру данных

Comment: ContentProvider - это подсистема доступа к данным, если она используется только вашим приложением то вы обязательно обратитесь к ней через приемник, активность или сервис, что вызовет вызов Application, если это создано для общего доступа, то ваше приложение и не должно вызываться.